# Theme state changes will be rerendered just once in ThemeProvider

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am a beginner in ReactJs and I want to change the theme just by clicking a button. But this just works for one time clicking a button, every click after will not have any effect.

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      theme: DarkTheme
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ThemeProvider theme={this.state.theme}>
        <div className="App">
          <Toolbar>
            <Button
              onClick={() => {
                this.setState({
                  theme: LightTheme
                });
              }}
            >
              <Typography color="primary" variant="body1">
                Light
              </Typography>
            </Button>
            <Button
              onClick={() => {
                this.setState({
                  theme: DarkTheme
                });
              }}
            >
              <Typography color="primary" variant="body1">
                Dark
              </Typography>
            </Button>
          </Toolbar>

          <Typography color="primary" variant="body1">
            Some text here that should always be displayed in primary color of current theme
          </Typography>
        </div>
      </ThemeProvider>
    );
  }
}
```

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/themeprovider-cpf0v?file=/src/App.js)

Can anybody explain what I did wrong?

*Using @material-ui/core@v.5.0.0-alpha.8*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perform a copy of your theme object when setting the new state and it should work

```
onClick={() => {
  this.setState({
    theme: {...LightTheme}
  });
}}
```

Comment: Honestly, the answer I provided is based on intuition. You are going to have to dig deep the MUI code or docs to find out. My guess is that on the child components, there is some comparison happening on the theme object and that some conditions fail (e.g., memoized objects) therefore some components don't update. The object returned by `createMuiTheme` is much bigger than you'd expect. Also see the usage of `React.memo` [here](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/400f8a64011b39eb4ae072233a99ad9862fd2c6f/packages/material-ui-styles/src/ThemeProvider/ThemeProvider.js)